# ENS renewal when ownership given to a smart contract

Tags: ens

I am planning to attempt to create a sub registry from my ENS domain, and potentially sell some of the sub domains (through allowing users to register them). From my reading I know it will be a necessary step to give up ownership of my ENS domain to the smart contract (else I'd retain control over the sub domains and nobody would buy them).

Does anyone know how this works when it come to renewal? I know I can renew the ENS from any address, but if I didn't, what happens? Can I assume the contract loses control of the domain in the same way an individual would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm the same would happen as with any ens owned by any wallet - if it expires it returns to ens and as such the smart contract would no longer control it.